# Add counter column to table

Tags: sql-server, counter

How can I insert values into table variable from another table by adding a column that counts original records. e.g.

```
 Value              Number    Value
----------  --->    ----------------
 56                 1         56
 78                 2         78
 90                 3         90
```

However, I cannot use an `IDENTITY(1,1)` to automatically generate counter values because I want to explicitly insert values into `Number` column. May be I should use [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29)?

Comment: Um - why can't you use an `IDENTITY` in a table variable?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever because I want to explicit insert values in this column further

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select row_number() over (order by (select 0)) as number,value from @tablevariable
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use 'ORDER BY' during your query, you may use:

```
SET @number=0;
SELECT @number:=@number+1 AS number, value FROM your_table;
```